# Find the total number of HTML tag used in a page using PHP

Tags: php, html

I've few website URLs with me, I'm trying to calculate the `MD5` hash of each website.

If the website submitted to my portal I would like to know, the same website submitted before in the portal.

So my idea was to extract the structure of the page and calculate `MD5` hash for the same.

For example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
   Test Data
 </body>
 </html>
```

I've used following PHP code to extract structure:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
// Find needed div
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('//html');
// What to do if divs more that one?
if ($elements->length != 1) die("some divs in the document have class 'content'");
// Take first
$div = $elements->item(0);
// Echo content of node $div
echo $doc->saveHTML($div);
```

However the above code will print complete HTML code. In my case, I would print/echo only HTML tags. Instead of the data e.g. "Test Data", which is mentioned in the above html code.

-- 
**EDIT**

I found the solution :

```
$pattern = "/<[^>]*>/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $doc->saveHTML($div), $results);
print_r($results);
```

Thank you for all

Comment: Stick to a hash, I can change a page but end up with the same number of HTML tags in it very easily

Comment: How i can calculate hash of the page where it always changes the data inside the html pages.

Comment: The files on disk are static, what is output to the browser may be different, but the .php script does not change